# Processes don't terminate

Tags: java, concurrency, process, command, java.util.concurrent

I am using Java `Executors.newWorkStealingPool();` for running several commands in parallel. Since some of these tasks are expected to timeout, I added a 2 second timeout for them.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd.split(" "));
Process p = null;
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
try {
    p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    BufferedReader errreader = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    BufferedReader outreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";           
    while ((line = outreader.readLine())!= null) 
    result.append(line + "\n");
    while ((line = errreader.readLine())!= null) 
        result.append(line + "\n");
    outreader.close();
    errreader.close();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        result.append("INTERRUPTED");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    finally {
        p.destroy();
    }
    ....
    return b; // b is boolean
```

Submitting tasks looks like this

```
List<ImmutablePair> curJobs = new ArrayList<ImmutablePair>();
for (int i = 0; i <  allMutants.size(); i++) {
    String mutant = allMutants.get(i);
    t = executor.submit(new mutTask(mutant));
    ImmutablePair pair = new ImmutablePair(mutant, t);
    curJobs.add(pair);
    }
```

and finally. I gather results in the following loop.

```
// data collection loop
for (int i = 0; i< curJobs.size(); i++) {
        ImmutablePair p = curJobs.get(i);
        String m= (String) p.getLeft();
    System.out.println(m);
        t = (Future<Boolean>) p.getRight();
    try {
        boolean res;
        try {
            res = t.get(2000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            res = true;
        }
        finally {
            t.cancel(true);
        }}
```

The problem is that, the timeout does not seem to terminate some of the commands or processes as it defined in the program. After few minutes data collection loops get very slow. The result of `ps` shows some jobs that are running well above the specified timeout and keeping CPU busy. My config is JDK8 on CentOS.

Comment: So, from the JavaDocs, we know *"Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the subprocess represented by this Process object has terminated, or the specified waiting time elapses."*, which means this method will return either when the process exists or the specified time elapses, so this means the process might still be running. Next, you then read the contents of the process output, which would mean, if the process is still ruining, it's either still processing output or is blocking...Generally I use a child `Thread` to read the input, when `waitFor` returns, stop these threads

Comment: ...and then destroy the process

Comment: Thanks. As you noted the problem was not checking the output of `p.waitFor(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`.

Answer (score 0):

As @MadProgrammer noted the problem was reading out/err buffers in case that processes terminate. To solve that, you need to check the output of  `p.waitFor(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`

```
    try {
        p = pb.start();
        boolean timeout = !p.waitFor(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        if (!timeout){
            BufferedReader errreader =
                     new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            BufferedReader outreader =
                     new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = outreader.readLine())!= null)
                result.append(line + "\n");
            while ((line = errreader.readLine())!= null)
                    result.append(line + "\n");
            outreader.close();
            errreader.close();
        }

    } catch ...
```